# Programmatically read a Queue's parameters

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've got a queue defined in `queue.xml` file

```
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>crawler</name>
        <rate>1/s</rate>
        <retry-parameters>
            ...
            <task-retry-limit>5</task-retry-limit>
        </retry-parameters>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

To obtain a queue in Java I'm using simple code

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("crawler");
```

Now I need to obtain the `task-retry-limit` value for given queue. Is it possible? I haven't found any method to do so in javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution based on @Tim Castelijns answer to read and parse the file programmatically.

[SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) in needed for this to work. Of course you can use other library to map XML to POJO.

Sample `queue.xml`

```
<queue-entries>
    <queue>
        <name>crawler</name>
        <rate>1/s</rate>
        <retry-parameters>
            <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
            <max-backoff-seconds>300</max-backoff-seconds>
            <max-doublings>2</max-doublings>
            <task-retry-limit>5</task-retry-limit>
        </retry-parameters>
    </queue>
</queue-entries>
```

How to read value

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
File source = new File("WEB-INF/queue.xml");
QueueEntries queueEntries = serializer.read(QueueEntries.class, source);
int retryLimit = queueEntries.getQueue().getRetryParameters().getTaskRetryLimit());
```

QueueEntries

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class QueueEntries {

    @Element
    private Queue queue;

    public Queue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }
}
```

Queue

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class Queue {

    @Element
    private String rate;
    @Element
    private String name;
    @Element(name = "retry-parameters")
    private RetryParameters retryParameters;

    public String getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public RetryParameters getRetryParameters() {
        return retryParameters;
    }
}
```

RetryParameters

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;

public class RetryParameters {

    @Element(name = "min-backoff-seconds")
    private String minBackoffSeconds;
    @Element(name = "max-backoff-seconds")
    private String maxBackoffSeconds;
    @Element(name = "max-doublings")
    private String maxDoublings;
    @Element(name = "task-retry-limit")
    private String taskRetryLimit;

    public String getMinBackoffSeconds() {
        return minBackoffSeconds;
    }

    public String getMaxDoublings() {
        return maxDoublings;
    }

    public String getMaxBackoffSeconds() {
        return maxBackoffSeconds;
    }

    public String getTaskRetryLimit() {
        return taskRetryLimit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears this is not possible.

If you look at [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.java), you will see that there is no such functionality defined.

The only property you can retrieve is the name, with `Queue.getName();`

---

I see no way to retrieve it using the current appengine api.

A hacky way as you call it, could be to parse the `queue.xml` file with an xml library, and extract the value manually.

Comment: Yes, it's true that retry limit getter is not defined in the Queue interface. I'm looking for a bit more hacky way to obtain the retry limit if possible.

Comment: Any chance for sample code how to read this file into memory? From my previous experience all the methods related to files throws exceptions on GAE. I've tried everything that came to my mind including reading `QueueImpl` fields using reflection, but it looks impossible to read these values at the moment.

Comment: @tomrozb for example something like this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ I guess the important part is that you get the path to the xml file right

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. I do not ask how to parse this file, I'm asking how to get handle to this file. From my experience all operations related to filesystem are not allowed on GAE.

Comment: May I suggest you ask that as a new, separate question? Because it's not directly related to the topic of this question