# Programmatically read queue.xml file

Tags: google-app-engine

This question is related to this problem: [Programmatically read a Queue's parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775675/programmatically-read-a-queues-parameters)

Is there a way to read `queue.xml` file's content programmatically on App Enigne? As far as I know all operations related to filesystem are prohibited on GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prohibited functions are related to the writing process in the file system (because does not exists in the sandbox) but the reading functions are available w/o problems.

the `new File();` object set the root in you war folder (or webapp if Maven project), so you can open any file under that folder.

You can try to create `new File("WEB-INF/queue.xml")` and then read it with the common ways to read an xml